# How does the Spin and Win works?

Tags: 8-ball-pool

Every time I spin it falls into 100 or 150 pool coins, how does this work?
How can I make it fall into another reward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While all of the regions on the wheel appear as though they'd be equally likely to land in, there are, in fact, varying odds for each section of the wheel; I can't find these odds anywhere but it's expected that the better the prize, the lower the odds for it. Consequently you'll find that you'll end up spinning the lower rewards very often, and there's not much you can do about it except hope you'll be lucky one day.

Comment: sounds sad, I'm never lucky:(

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, its all about probability, the higher the prize is, the lower the chances you have for a jackpot. I found the probability chart:[image]

Source:https://www.reddit.com/r/8BallPool/comments/mbbbgw/outcome_of_100_spin_and_wins/